# Integration work: $\int\sqrt{\frac{2-x}{x-3}} \ \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int\sqrt{\dfrac{2-x}{x-3}}\mathrm dx$$

My approach

I=$$\int\sqrt{\dfrac{2-x}{x-3}}\mathrm dx$$

I= $$\int\frac{2-x}{\sqrt{-x^2+5x-6}}\mathrm dx$$

Next I substituted 2-x =t and processed but I am not getting the answer. Can you guys help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: try to compute $I$ via the substitution
$$
\frac{2-x}{x-3}=t
$$

Comment: Can I ask you what is the idea behind this substitution?

Comment: @harambe It is a standard substitution that I learned as a student, I can't provide any extraordinary intuition behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Practical way is to choose $$\sqrt{\dfrac{2-x}{x-3}}=t$$ so, $x=\frac{3t^2+2}{t^2+1}$ ans then...

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2-x}{x-3}=t^2$$
$$\frac{1}{(x-3)^2}dx=2tdt$$
$$x=\frac{3t^2+2}{t^2+1}$$
$$x-3=\frac{3t^2+2}{t^2+1}-3=-\frac{1}{t^2+1}$$

$$\int t\cdot2tdt\cdot(\frac{-1}{t^2+1})^2=\int\frac{2t^2}{(t^2+1)^2}dt$$
Now solving 
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{t^2}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$$
Write it as
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{t^2+1-1}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(t^2+1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$$